# Error raro en Eclipse: funciona, pero me aparece el subrayado rojo en el JOptionPane

Tags: java, eclipse

Empecé a programar en Eclipse. Tengo un error en el código que escribí (ver los comentarios en el código):

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class SumaConJOptionPane {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String usuario, aux1, aux2;
        int a, b;
        //                          Se solicita nombre de usuario

        usuario = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese nombre de usuario");
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


        //                          muestra el nombre y le indica al usario que se va a hacer una suma

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Muy bien " + usuario + "! V    amos a hacer una suma");
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        //                          A continuacion solicita el ingreso del primer numero

        aux1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa un numero: ");
        a = Integer.parseInt(aux1); // En esta linea lo que hace es convertir al 'string' del JOptionPane en un 'int'
        // con el metodo Integer.parseInt(aqui va la variable del JOptionPane)

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


        //                          Solicita el segundo numero

        aux2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa el otro numero: ");
        b = Integer.parseInt(aux2); // En esta linea lo que hace es convertir al 'string' del JOptionPane en un 'int'
        // con el metodo Integer.parseInt(aqui va la variable del JOptionPane

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        //                          Finalmente nombra al usuario, muestra los numeros ingresados, y el resultado de la suma entre dichos numeros

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bien " + usuario + "! " + a + " + " + b + " es igual a " + (a + b) + "");
    }
}
```

Lo que pasa es... funciona, pero de todos modos me aparece el subrayado rojo en el `JOptionPane` indicándome un error, ¡pero funciona de todos modos!.

¿Alguien puede decirme qué podría ser? No sé si será sintaxis o el JRE o JDK, ya los revisé y todos están en la misma versión.

Comment: Acabo de revisar el codigo en mi IDE para ver lo que dices, y no me sale absolutamente nada... a lo mejor sea error del Netbeans y lo tienes que reiniciar nada mas.

Comment: uso Eclipse @TwoDent , como ves, tal parece que esta todo bien, sin embargo me aparece ese tipica bombita de luz con la X al lado indicandome el error. La verdad que no se que sera, hasta ahora no he tenido problemas ejecutando el codigo, mi duda esta en que que sera lo que Eclipse interpreta como error, y si esto me impedira seguir escribiendo codigo, intento hacer las cosas bien, y pasa que aunque funcione, lo mismo queda un poco mal que me largue error ¬¬'

Comment: Disculpa por mencionar netbeans,  es el que siempre uso yo jaja, pues bueno puedes seguir escribiendo tranquilo... ahi postie una posible situacion que pudo ocurrirte...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El codigo que has pegado en tu pregunta, esta perfecto, no hay errores en el. Creo que tengo la sospecha de que te marcaba en **rojo** en el **JOptionPane** porque aun no habias importado **la clase**.

```
import javax.swing.*;
```

Que simplemente tambien podias importarlo asi, ya que al usar el asterisco (*) importa todas las clases de la **libreria swing**:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
```

No creo que le hayas dado click al foquito del error que te muestra Eclipse, ya que si lo hubieses hecho, solo te importaria la clase como lo escribi aqui en la segunda manera.

Comment: Uso ECLIPSE. También probé de la manera que me decís, y resulta lo mismo.

Comment: Mis disculpas de nuevo, Eclipse no te muestra ni un mensaje de error?

Comment: No hay de que disculparse! No te preocupes jaja, y mira, unos de los errores que me marca al acercar el mouse al foquito es **-Access restriccion: The type JOptionPane is not accessible due to restriction on requiered library C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\rt.jar** , todos son los mismos errores

Comment: Aqui hay una pregunta con tu problema (esta en ingles por cierto...) espero que te sirva de ayuda!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860187/access-restriction-on-class-due-to-restriction-on-required-library-rt-jar